# Changing the alpha of the paint changes the alpha of whole paint view

Tags: java, android

i am working on a paint application , when i am trying to change to value of alpha of the paint by mPaint.setAlpha((int) (255 -opaciyBrush * 2.53f));
where opacitybrush is the integer getting the value from the seek bar.
and yes i am initializing the PaintingView class every time on onStopTrackingTouch of the seek bar.
so the problem is that when i am trying to change the value of alpha ,it changes the value previous drawn lines on the canvas.(i.e changes the value of whole paint view )
i want to fix this, my code is

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public PaintingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        onCanvasInitialization();
    }

    private void onCanvasInitialization() {

        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        mPaint.setColor(MainActivity.colorchanger);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();
        Paint newPaint = new Paint(mPaint);
        Container.paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(mPath, newPaint));
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(widthBrush / 4 + 1);
        mPaint.setAlpha((int) (255 - opacityBrush * 2.53f));

    }
```

which is working prefect accept the alpha part.

Comment: Please stop flagging your questions for moderator attention unless you want to risk them getting closed instead of answered. "it is not getting answers" is **not** a valid reason to flag. If this continues you may lose the privilege to ask questions entirely.

Comment: ok my bad..but i have not be answered yet